# Cannot use REPLACE function properly in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have an SQL table whose columns are State_Code, School_Code and School_Type.

Sample Data:

```
State_Code    School_Code     School_Type
 01            01014874        1
 01            01018790        2
 1             10189900        1
 1             10277689        1
```

*(Note: 1st and 2nd digit of School_Code is the actual state-code while its 3rd and 4th digit is the District_Code of that particular state)*

Now, if I fire this query:

```
Select COUNT(School_Code) from Table1 where State_Code='1'+0;
```

It will return the number of schools present in the state, with code '1'; i.e. *4*;

But if I want to retrieve the number of schools present in a state DISTRICT-WISE; I would fire this query:

```
Select State_Code,SUBSTRING(School_Code,3,2) AS District_Code,COUNT(School_Code) AS Number_of_Schools_In_District FROM Table1 GROUP BY State_Code+0;
```

This query returns me this output:

```
State_Code     District_Code      Number_of_Schools_In_District
   01               01                         2
   1                18                         1
   1                27                         1
```

But the correct output is:

```
State_Code     District_Code      Number_of_Schools_In_District
   01               01                         3
   1                02                         1
```

This is due to the incorrect data entered by user in SQL table for column School_Code. State '1' and '01' are actually the same state i.e. '01'. But since School-Code in the 3rd and 4th row does not start with '0', this lead to the incorrect behavior in the output.

So to resolve this problem, I will have to use this logic:

```
*If number of characters in State_Code is 1 and School_Code does not start with '0', then a '0' should be prefixed to the School_Code value to get the correct District_Code value.*
```

I tried this:

```
Select State_Code,SUBSTRING(School_Code,3,2) AS District_Code,COUNT(School_Code) AS     Number_of_Schools_In_District FROM Table1 WHERE IF CHARACTER_LENGTH(State_Code)=1 AND School_Code NOT LIKE '0%' THEN REPLACE(School_Code,School_Code,CONCAT(0,School_Code)) END IF GROUP BY State_Code+0, SUBSTRING(School_Code,3,2)+0;
```

My expectation was if any value in State_code is a single digit and its corresponding School Code does not start with '0', then this will append '0' to it and then calculate district code taking the 3rd and 4th digit. But this does not happen. Still I get the error.

```
Note: I don't want to update original SQL table values.
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Why is the field not `INT`?

Comment: I got this type of data only. Not allowed to change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below query

```
Select State_Code, IF(CHARACTER_LENGTH(State_Code)=1, SUBSTRING(School_Code,2,2), SUBSTRING(School_Code,3,2)) AS District_Code,COUNT(School_Code) AS     Number_of_Schools_In_District FROM Table1 WHERE GROUP BY State_Code+0, SUBSTRING(School_Code,3,2)+0;
```